# When does Spyder's "?" suffix yield doc string?

Tags: pyspark, spyder

I used Anaconda to install Python 3.9 and PySpark on Windows 10.  I am following [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-rename-dataframe-column)
to manipulate `DataFrame` `Column`s.  I've cut it down signficantly to
arrive at the following minimal working example.  It consists of 4
sections: (1) Data for DataFrame; (2) Schema for DataFrame; (3) Start
Spark and create DataFrame; and (4) Create new schema to rename "name"
subfields.

```
# Data for DataFrame
dataDF = [(('James','Smith'),'1991-04-01'),
  (('Michael',''),'2000-05-19'),
]

# Schema definition needed to create DataFrame. The first "name"
# field consists of 2 subfields for first and last name
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
schema = StructType([
        StructField('name', StructType([
             StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
             StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
             ])),
         StructField('dob', StringType(), True),
         ])

# Start a Spark session and create the DataFrame "df"
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = dataDF, schema = schema)

# Define a new schema for renaming the "name" subfields
schema2 = StructType([
    StructField("fname",StringType()),
    StructField("lname",StringType())])

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.select( col("name").cast(schema2), col("dob") ).printSchema()
```

I tried to look up what `cast` did.  It didn't seem like the Python
[`cast`](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/07/06/python-type-hints-how-to-use-typing-cast)
because it was a method of `col("name")`, which was of class `Column`.
I *unsuccessfully* tried to pull up the doc string by adding
Spyder's `?` suffix to `cast`, *as accessed via a Column object:*

```
df.name.cast?
```

The reams of errors are captured in the Annex below.

Since (say) `df.select?` brings up the required doc string, why
doesn't it work for `df.name.cast?`?  More specifically, ***when can
the `?` be expected to work?***

I note that `df.name` and `df.name.cast` are recognized objects

```
In [98]: df.name
Out[98]: Column<'name'>

In [99]: df.name.cast
Out[99]: <bound method Column.cast of Column<'name'>>
```

Here is another example of when an object (a class
`DataFrame`) is recognized, but its doc string help cannot be pulled up:

```
In [41]: sys.modules["pyspark.sql"].DataFrame
Out[41]: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

In [42]: sys.modules["pyspark.sql"].DataFrame?
Object `DataFrame` not found.
```

## Annex: Errors from `df.name.cast?`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[97], line 1
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('pinfo', 'df.name.cast')

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2414 in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\namespace.py:58 in pinfo
    self.shell._inspect('pinfo', oname, detail_level=detail_level,

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:1795 in _inspect
    pmethod(

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py:782 in pinfo
    info_b: Bundle = self._get_info(

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py:738 in _get_info
    info_dict = self.info(obj, oname=oname, info=info, detail_level=detail_level)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py:838 in info
    if info and info.parent and hasattr(info.parent, HOOK_NAME):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\column.py:1369 in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Comment: `?` is not specific to spyder. It can be used in any python interpreter to see the docstring of a class or a function.

Comment: @Steven: Are you sure?  I just ran `pyspark` at the Conda prompt.  Issuing `spark` yields `<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x000002778DDFBAC0>`, but issuing `spark?` yields `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. There is a caret symbol pointing to the `?`.

Comment: In case it matters, I added the context as the opening sentence in the question: Anaconda, Python 3.9, Windows 10.

Comment: you're typing this directly in "python" shell ? That's probably why it does not work. It works with more advanced shell like ipython

Comment: The console in Spyder runs IPython.  At least, it does in mine.  The very first lines of output include `IPython 8.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.`